# NextJS SSR on AWS ECS + Fargate

Tags: next.js, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

My team is trying to deploy a NextJS app with SSR on AWS ECS/Fargate but we are facing a 504 Gateway Time-out error. It seems like getServerSideProps is never called.

Are NextJS features such as SSR still possible given our setup? We are not using Amplify for company reasons.

I've tried running the Docker image locally, and it works perfectly fine.

This is our Dockerfile:

```html
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Not enough information provided to help you. Yes SSR is possible on ECS/Fargate. It should be no different than the container running locally. You probably have some sort of network configuration issue, or target group configuration issue, which is why the load balancer is giving you a gateway timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

For fargate, i suggest you use aws copilot. It’s straightforward since it does network configuration automatically.